# Gtk+ Error when Copy / Paste performed outside of application

Tags: gtk, clipboard, gdk

I'm fairly new to Gtk. I'm working on a GUI application. Everything works great until I press Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V to copy/paste (in an outside application like excel). I am using Windows 8 64bit with a Mingw 32bit compiler. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: THe error is: (GUI.exe:7792): Gdk-CRITICAL **: inner_clipboard_window_procedure: assertion `success' failed

Comment: I just tried to recreate this Gdk error and now it isn't showing up. This bug seems like it will be pretty temperamental.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to hit the same assertion error by inducing infinite recursion (my trick was to call paste_clipboard() inside a paste_clipboard signal handler - fun fun!). Possibly you had something that responded to a clipboard change by changing the clipboard?