# Error by doing Copy Paste with win32com (Glade GTK Python)

Tags: python, clipboard, copy-paste, glade, win32com

I have a simple function "Copy", for copy and paste with win32com. It runs several times without problems.

But if i use a button(GUI GTK Glade) to trigger the function "Copy()", it runs only once. The second time i get the following Error:

```
Gdk-CRITICAL (recursed) **: inner_clipboard_window_procedure:
assertion `success' failed
aborting...
```

Can you help me ?

CopyPaste:

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client

def Copy():
    # Pfad zum Template
    path_to_temp = r"C:\004_Python_Workspace\Persek\Template.xls"

    # Pfad zum Testpaket
    xlsPath = r"C:\004_Python_Workspace\Testfolder\Testanweisung_LK_ASL.xls" 

    # Blattname im Template und im Testpaket
    Sheet = 'ECU_Config'

    excel_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application') 

    ###### Kopiere ECU_Config aus Template #####
    excel_workbook1 = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(path_to_temp)

    excel_workbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).UsedRange.Copy()

    ###### Fuege in das neue Testpaket ein #####      
    excel_workbook2 = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(xlsPath)
    excel_workbook2.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('A1').PasteSpecial()
    excel_workbook2.worksheets(Sheet).Columns('A:B').AutoFit()
    excel_workbook2.Close(SaveChanges=True)
    del excel_workbook2

    excel_workbook1.Close()
    del excel_workbook1
    excel_app.Quit()
```

Glade GtK Trigger with a button:

```
def on_debug_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    CopyPaste_Error.Copy()
```

Update 1a:
Until "UsedRange.Copy()" line is all the same.

```
    excel_workbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).UsedRange.Copy()
    excel_app.Quit()
```

Comment: Is this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690277/gtk-error-when-copy-paste-performed-outside-of-application

Comment: Hello WombatPM, maybe its the same but there is no Solution. What i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i found the solution, but i dont know why. I include "win32clipboard"

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client
import win32clipboard

def Copy():

    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()

    # Pfad zum Template
    path_to_temp = r"C:\004_Python_Workspace\Persek\Template.xls"

    # Pfad zum Testpaket
    xlsPath = r"C:\004_Python_Workspace\Testfolder\Testanweisung_LK_ASL.xls" 

    # Blattname im Template und im Testpaket
    Sheet = 'ECU_Config'

    excel_app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application') 

    ###### Kopiere ECU_Config aus Template #####
    excel_workbook1 = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(path_to_temp)

    excel_workbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).UsedRange.Copy()

    ###### Fuege in das neue Testpaket ein #####      
    excel_workbook2 = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(xlsPath)
    excel_workbook2.Worksheets(Sheet).Range('A1').PasteSpecial()
    excel_workbook2.worksheets(Sheet).Columns('A:B').AutoFit()
    excel_workbook2.Close(SaveChanges=True)
    del excel_workbook2

    excel_workbook1.Close()
    del excel_workbook1
    excel_app.Quit()

    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: +1 can't explain either but it works. You should accept it too so closes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not an answer but didn't fit in a comment:

Can you try the following, and post in which case you still have problem:

1. If you just remove the `UsedRange.Copy()` line
2. If you just remove the `PasteSpecial` line
3. If you remove both the `UsedRange.Copy()` line and the `PasteSpecial` line
4. If you remove lines from `excel_workbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).UsedRange.Copy()` to `del excel_workbook2`
5. If you remove all the lines from `excel_app = win32com...` to end of Copy(), and remove the import of win32com

Update:

Based on results by user3231222, two more tests:

1. Confirm that if comment out everything between (but not including) the lines `UsedRange.Copy()` and `excel_app.Quit()` that error still occurs.
2. If it does, check whether you get same error if you replace the spreadsheet loaded with one that has say just a couple of cells with text in them (no formulas or formatting etc)

Comment: 1. Error because Paste without Copy before is not possible  
2. Error: inner_clipboard_window_procedure  
3. no Error
4. no Error
5. no Error

Comment: Update: 1a, Comment out everything between these stated also workbook1.close and del workbook1  --> I get the error in the first run

Comment: Update: 1b, Comment out everything between UsedRange.Copy() and excel_workbook1.Close() --> I get the same error in the second run

Comment: Update: 2. I get the same Error

Comment: update 1a is strange! can you run again? Can you extend your question to include the script that causes error on first try? and verify it is repeatable (always on first try).

Comment: update 1a: Yes it is repeatable. The last two lines are "excel_workbook1.Worksheets(Sheet).UsedRange.Copy()" and "excel_app.Quit()"